# Facebook like box plugin for twitter bootstrap

Tags: facebook, twitter-bootstrap

Facebook's like box iframe isn't working for me. Can someone point out why? Here's my code BTW it works on a different bootstrap theme

```
<div class ="section" id= "lastsectionmainpage">
    <div class ="row">
      <div class ="col-lg-12">
          <div class ="col-md-4">
      <img src= "img/sg.jpg">
      <h4 style ="color:white"> More Testimonials</h4>
    </div> <!-- end of 4 -->


            <div class ="col-md-4">
             <h4 style= "color:white"> SEE OUR IMAGE GALLERY </h4>
              <!-- button here -->
             </div> <!-- end of 4 -->


            <div class ="col-md-4">
        <iframe src="http//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F   
       2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;width&amp;height=590& 
       &amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&
       amp;show_border=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;
        overflow:hidden; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>    
       </div>

          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

After "http", you forgot ":":

```
<iframe src="http://www.fa...
```

Even better: remove "http" so the protocol from the website will be used:

```
<iframe src="//www.fa...
```

Always use the code generator for getting the correct code for the social plugins: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button